# How do I create a map from 90 zip codes from city of chicago

Tags: python-2.7, data-visualization

My project is about to show my audience where do rich people and poor people live in the city of Chicago. I have 90 different zip codes and My job is to make a map for the 90 zip codes and shade the area with rich people and poor people live. I have the data for 90 zip codes with their gross income from 2017.

Comment: Please show some effort. What have you tried? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Google Maps, OpenStreetMap or MapBox with Leaflet might be a good way to visualize what you are trying to do. Python can supply data to JavaScript, which can then use mapping APIs to plot, color-code etc. Nice project. We'd love to see you attempt something.

Comment: So, I'm new to programming and I just need help get started on it. I have not started the project yet but I need help to get started on it.

Comment: Is there a reason that the question is tagged "python-2.7"? If you are starting a new project, I strongly advise you to use Python 3.

Comment: we're using python 2.7.

Comment: OK, but why? Who are "we"? Python 2.7 will soon be unsupported: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: well, All my exercise I have been doing on 2.7. So, I don't want to switch over to 3 at the moment. If make simpler in 3 then I might switch it.